# iPhone: Cocos2d how to make a sequence

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I have two logos, which I want to come in after each other.

I'd like to use CCFadeIn and CCFadeOut.

I have Logo1, and then I want it to CCFadeIn, then I want it to stay for 2 seconds, then make it fade out using CCFadeOut, and then make Logo2 CCFadeIn for 1 second, stay for 2 seconds and then go away during 1 second with CCFadeOut.

How I would make this I'm not completely sure. I can't seem to find a way to make a CCAction fire a method (let's say -finishedFadingInLogo1:), so I don't know how to do this.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

...somewhere:...

```
[logo1 runAction:
  [CCSequence actions:
    [CCFadeIn actionWithDuration:SOMETIME], 
    [CCDelayTime actionWithDuration:2], 
    [CCFadeOut actionWithDuration:SOMEOTHERTIME], 
    [CCCallFunc actionWithTarget:SOMETARGET selector:@selector(finishedFadingInLogo1)], 
    nil
  ]
];
```

...

```
-(void)finishedFadingInLogo1
{
   [logo2 runAction:blah, yada, nil];
}
```

make sense? There are other actions similar to `CCCallFunc` that take args and such...

Comment: Tip: better formatting would help to illustrate the point. Personally i also wouldn't stuff all the actions into the sequence line, instead create local variables that holds each action. Makes for much better readable (and maintainable) code.

Answer (score 4):

For better readability, Colin's answer reformatted:

```
id fadein = [CCFadeIn actionWithDuration:2];
id delay = [CCDelayTime actionWithDuration:2];
id fadeout = [CCFadeOut actionWithDuration:2];
id call = [CCCallFunc actionWithTarget:self selector:@selector(doneFading)];
CCSequence* sequence = [CCSequence actions:fadein, delay, fadeout, call, nil];
[aNode runAction:sequence];
```